# Why is this situation $\Omega$, rather than Big-O?

Tags: algorithms

In this sitaution how is $n^{100}\times 2^n = \Omega(3^n)$? To me $2^n< 3^n$, making it Big O, not $\Omega$?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.  What does $\Omega$ mean?

Comment: Where did you see this assertion? Do you have some context?

Comment: @JoshuaZ I saw it with examples of comparing the asymptotic growth of each function, I believe it is an error, but I could be wrong :)

Comment: @herbsteinberg ()≥()

Comment: Yes, it's backwards.  $3^n=\Omega(n^{100}2^n)$  which is to say, $n^{100}2^n=O(3^n$)$

Comment: It would be good to clarify which [big omega notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) you are intending.